# Accessing zoo object from list of lists returned from RJSDMX download of ECB data

Tags: subset

I am having trouble understanding or finding information on how to access the list elements returned from the European Central Bank download using the RJSDMX package.  I am downloading time series for all European countries, and I need to automate the merging of these data sets into one zoo object for each series.  The code for the download I use and some general idea of the structure of the data returned is:

```
require(RJSDMX)
total_loans_m <- getSDMX('ECB','BSI.M.BE|BG|CZ|DK|DE|EE|IE|EL|ES|FR|HR|IT|CY|LV|LT|LU|HU|MT|NL|AT|PL|PT|RO|SI|FI|SE|UK|IS|NO|CH|ME|MK|RS|TR|BA.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E')
> class(total_loans_m)
[1] "list"
>str(total_loans_m[1])
List of 1
 $ BSI.M.AT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E:‘zooreg’ series from Sep 1997 to Aug 2014
  Data: atomic [1:204] 83066 81829 82413 81271 83366 ...
  ..- attr(*, "STATUS")= chr [1:204] "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
  ..- attr(*, "FREQ")= chr "M"
  ..- attr(*, "REF_AREA")= chr "AT"
  ..- attr(*, "ADJUSTMENT")= chr "N"
  ..- attr(*, "BS_REP_SECTOR")= chr "A"
  ..- attr(*, "BS_ITEM")= chr "A20"
  ..- attr(*, "MATURITY_ORIG")= chr "A"
  ..- attr(*, "DATA_TYPE")= chr "1"
  ..- attr(*, "COUNT_AREA")= chr "U2"
  ..- attr(*, "BS_COUNT_SECTOR")= chr "1000"
  ..- attr(*, "CURRENCY_TRANS")= chr "Z01"
  ..- attr(*, "BS_SUFFIX")= chr "E"
  ..- attr(*, "DECIMALS")= chr "'0'"
  ..- attr(*, "UNIT")= chr "'EUR'"
  ..- attr(*, "UNIT_MULT")= chr "'6'"
  ..- attr(*, "COLLECTION")= chr "'E'"
  ..- attr(*, "TITLE_COMPL")= chr "'Austria, Outstanding amounts at the end of the period (stocks), MFIs excluding ESCB reporting sector - Loans, Total maturity, "| __truncated__
  Index: Class 'yearmon'  num [1:204] 1998 1998 1998 1998 1998 ...
  Frequency: 12 
> names(total_loans_m)
 [1] "BSI.M.AT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [2] "BSI.M.BE.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [3] "BSI.M.BG.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [4] "BSI.M.CY.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [5] "BSI.M.CZ.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [6] "BSI.M.DE.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [7] "BSI.M.EE.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [8] "BSI.M.ES.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
 [9] "BSI.M.FI.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[10] "BSI.M.FR.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[11] "BSI.M.HR.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[12] "BSI.M.HU.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[13] "BSI.M.IE.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[14] "BSI.M.IT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[15] "BSI.M.LT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[16] "BSI.M.LU.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[17] "BSI.M.LV.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[18] "BSI.M.MT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[19] "BSI.M.NL.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[20] "BSI.M.PL.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[21] "BSI.M.PT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[22] "BSI.M.RO.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[23] "BSI.M.SE.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
[24] "BSI.M.SI.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E"
```

So, the RJSDMX returns a list of 24 lists (one for each country), with each having a zoo object indicated by the long string indicated in the `names()` call.  I can access the zoo object by calling, for example `total_loans_m$BSI.M.AT.N.A.A20.A.1.U2.1000.Z01.E` but I cannot find info on how to call that element of the list within the list, as I would also like to rename each column by the country name rather than the long string.  I was hoping some sort of `for` loop could get it done, calling each of the 24 lists, accessing the 'zooreg' series and merging it with each of the other 24 countries, and appending the "REF_AREA" country code as the column name of the zooreg object.  Can anyone explain how to determine what element each of these is being stored in, I cannot find any info that talks about complex lists within list or how to access attributes that makes sense to me, or I don't know the proper terminology to do the correct search.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see which list within a list you are referring to.
`total_loans_m` is a list containing 24 elements; each one of these elements is a `zoo` object (not another list). What is supposed to be in the list you are looking for, the values of the series, the names,...?

Comment: Hi [user3701213](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3701213/user3701213), if you need to read SDMX docs, data or other doc types (e.g. codelists / datastructures), you can also try the rsdmx package. It's available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsdmx/). You can also check the [rsdmx documentation](https://github.com/opensdmx/rsdmx/wiki) that gives examples on several datasources including ECB. The difference is that you will be able to read entirely the dataset as ``data.frame``. Some attributes (like countries in your example will be handled in a single column). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you want to merge the series, and name them by the country name by columns. How about this?

```
x <- do.call("cbind", total_loans_m)
names(x) <- substr(names(total_loans_m), 7, 8)
head(x)
#             AT     BE BG CY CZ        DE EE     ES        FI     FR HR HU
# Sep 1997 83066 139478 NA NA NA  943811.6 NA 199701  8186.883 822222 NA NA
# Oct 1997 81829 144261 NA NA NA  966783.4 NA 199076 10144.759 832853 NA NA
# Nov 1997 82413 144122 NA NA NA 1002784.5 NA 199520  9730.008 847246 NA NA
# Dec 1997 81271 123517 NA NA NA 1005940.2 NA 209386  9860.690 849077 NA NA
# Jan 1998 83366 129742 NA NA NA 1004540.3 NA 209291  9152.450 881863 NA NA
# Feb 1998 83932 133066 NA NA NA 1010344.0 NA 211616 10289.569 880293 NA NA
#                IE     IT LT       LU LV MT     NL PL    PT RO SE SI
# Sep 1997 31905.98 187778 NA 220047.4 NA NA  62951 NA 38476 NA NA NA
# Oct 1997 33190.95 190900 NA 229895.1 NA NA  66195 NA 40482 NA NA NA
# Nov 1997 35180.63 190191 NA 224347.8 NA NA  72708 NA 39459 NA NA NA
# Dec 1997 37405.22 205422 NA 216277.9 NA NA 129542 NA 41510 NA NA NA
# Jan 1998 38221.66 199245 NA 241180.3 NA NA 142657 NA 39441 NA NA NA
# Feb 1998 38102.30 204014 NA 241650.3 NA NA 137135 NA 40164 NA NA NA
```

Comment: that works great.  i was missing cbind or thought the data structure was such that it wouldn't works properly.  thanks for pointing out do.call as well, never seen that before either.